# Drawing anti-aliased round-capped line with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I'm trying to create a stylised timeline for an audio player. I would like to draw a nice thick line with round caps at the ends. I thought it would be relatively trivial to do this with `canvas`. However, I'm finding that at least in Chrome on Mac OS, the lines are not anti-aliased; and also (possibly as a consequence) the line caps are elongated, rather than perfect half-circles.

What perplexes me is that when I view the [W3 Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/playcanvas.asp?filename=playcanvas_lineCap&preval=round) the line *is* anti-aliased, with the expected caps. This makes me wonder if something in my code is triggering a non-anti-aliased mode in the browser...

Here is my full code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: #212b69;
        }

        .centering {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #timeline {
            width: 60%;
            height: 50px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="centering">
        <canvas id="timeline" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var ctx = timeline.getContext('2d');
        var centrline = timeline.height/2;

        // ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5); // I have tried the half-pixel trick

        // line settings
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = 30;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";

        // draw test stroke
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(20, centrline);
        ctx.lineTo(60, centrline+10); // offset to show aliasing of edges
        ctx.stroke();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My result:

[image: aliased line screenshot]

Compared with W3Schools result:

[image: anti-aliased line from W3Schools]

I understand from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261090/html5-canvas-and-anti-aliasing) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element) that vector anti-aliasing is determined by the browser. Note also that I've tried the trick of translating the canvas by a half-pixel to kick it into anti-aliasing mode. If there is no way to get `canvas` to get what I want it to do, is there some other method? Given that I only want to create a relatively simple shape...

Comment: You're distorting the canvas with the css rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the following css rule and the shape will stop skewing.

```
#timeline {
            width: 60%;
            height: 50px;
        }
```

Here's a working example without skew: [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/8c8p50Lp/3/)

```js
var timeline = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var ctx = timeline.getContext('2d');
        var centrline = timeline.height/2;

        // ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5); // I have tried the half-pixel trick

        // line settings
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.lineWidth = 30;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "white";

        // draw test stroke
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(20, centrline);
        ctx.lineTo(60, centrline+10); // offset to show aliasing of edges
        ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #212b69;
}

.centering {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centering">
        <canvas id="timeline" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did wonder if the percentage width was a problem and replaced that by a pixel width. So the CSS width and height are different from the canvas width and height attributes? In order to achieve a 60% width-style behaviour, will it be necessary to resize by Javascript with a `resize` event listener?