# Avoiding anti-aliasing with round painting in react-konva

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs, konvajs-reactjs

I am trying to create a app with Konva and react-konva where the user can freely draw anything he wants on the stage, but mainly to use the mouse as a pen or a erasor.

The user can only use two colors: red and green. Although, the user have to see the background. So the colors I am using are actually `rgba(255,0,0,125)` and `rgba(0,255,0,125)`, so they can see the image in the Konva.Stage while they draw on it.

The free drawing region:

```js
const Region = forwardRef(({ lines }, ref) => {
  const [stroke, setStroke] = useState(30);
  const line1Ref = useRef(null);
  const line2Ref = useRef(null);
  console.log(line1Ref?.current);
  return (
    <Layer ref={ref}>
      {lines.map((line, i) => (
        <>
          <Line
            ref={line1Ref}
            points={line.points}
            stroke="black"
            strokeWidth={stroke}
            lineCap="round"
            lineJoin="round"
            tension={0.5}
            globalCompositeOperation="destination-out"
          />
          <Line
            ref={line2Ref}
            points={line.points}
            stroke={line.color}
            strokeWidth={stroke}
            tension={0.5}
            lineCap="round"
            lineJoin="round"
          />
        </>
      ))}
    </Layer>
  );
});
```

The stage is drawn as follows

```js
const Konva = (props) => {

const regionRef = useRef(null);
  const [drawing, setDrawing] = useState(false);
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);
  const [finish, setFinish] = useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [color, setColor] = useState('rgba(255,0,0,0.49)');
  const stageRef = useRef(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (props.url) {
      const { url } = props;
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = () => {
        setImage(img);
        setFinish(true);
      };
      img.src = url;
    }
  }, [matchingFrame]);

const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    setDrawing(true);
    const pos = e.target.getStage().getPointerPosition();
    setLines((prevLines) => {
      return [...prevLines, { color, points: [pos.x, pos.y] }];
    });
  };
  const handleMouseUp = () => {
    setDrawing(false);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!drawing) {
      return;
    }
    const stage = e.target.getStage();
    const point = stage.getPointerPosition();
    const lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1];
    // add point
    lastLine.points = lastLine.points.concat([point.x, point.y]);

    // replace last
    lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1, lastLine);
    setLines(lines.concat());
  };
  
  if(!image) return null; 
  
  return (<Stage
              ref={stageRef}
              width={image.width}
              height={image.height}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
              onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
              onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
              onMouseLeave={handleMouseUp}
            >
              <Layer ref={imgRef}>
                <KonvaImage image={image} />
              </Layer>

              <Region ref={regionRef} lines={lines} color={color} />
            </Stage>)
  }
```

After the drawing I convert the data to an encoded array mask. Althought, the joint points between the colors have different rgba besides the ones I desired due to the   anti-aliasing that make the pen looks curved. If I ignore this mix of colors, there will be pixels with no color when they should have, like in the image [image: removed mixed colors in the pixel]

Is there any way to avoid this colors interpolation? The idea I have now is to set this pixels into a nearest neighbor approach where I would fill them with the nearest color, red or green.

The code developed is based on the demos developed by Anton Lavrenov. [Image labeling](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Image_Labeling.html) and [Free drawing](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Free_Drawing.html)

Comment: May not be a direct answer and do not be put off by the age - there is some good discussion about  antialiasing. There are some interesting suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261090/html5-canvas-and-anti-aliasing particularly this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49357655/7073944. Note the question was about HTML5 canvas but Konva is constrained to the capabilities of the HTML5 canvas.