# Drawing a single pixel w/canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Is it possible to make say, a zoomed in canvas where every 5x5 block is actually 1 pixel in the final image and how do you "paint" the pixel with a color stored in a variable onclick? Any code I've tested ends up being strokes, clicking does nothing for some reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the best way to set a single pixel in an HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899799/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-single-pixel-in-an-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="width:100px; height:100px" width="5" height="5"></canvas>

<script>

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    //Background
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);



    canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        var x = Math.floor(e.x * canvas.width / parseInt(canvas.style.width));
        var y = Math.floor(e.y * canvas.height / parseInt(canvas.style.height));


        //Zoomed in red 'square'
        context.fillStyle = "#F00";
        context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);

    }, true);

</script>
```

Edit: Added click functionality

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Cmpde/

Comment: For some bizarre reason this doesn't work on FF10 but works on IE.

Comment: Is there any way to disable antialiasing completely?

Comment: @jmoon Don't know (actually I don't think you can), but you could just make a big canvas with a bigger width/height (as in, everything is in proportion), and draw squares that are 20x20. As to why id doesn't work, it could have something to do with how I'm getting mouse coordinates (MouseEvent.x).

Comment: The issue is that I need it to be an exact sized base64 png, and only look larger when editing

Comment: In moz and webkit, you can disable canvas smoothing with: `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false; ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`