# Suggestions for plotting heat map of 17K x 1K data points in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, heatmap

Using **SVG** rectangle  for each data point is extremely slow. Please suggest some workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data like that SVG is not optimal. Use **Canvas** instead and look up information about pixel manipulation like this:

[What's the best way to set a single pixel in an HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899799/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-single-pixel-in-an-html5-canvas)