# Mark spots in image

Tags: javascript, user-interface, jquery-ui, frontend, createjs

I am new to fronted implementation. 
I have a stock image of a vehicle that I'm using as a base for my users to mark damage on. I would like the user to be able to edit this image to show damage, and save this newly created image.

The image below visualises this concept. If anyone has an idea on how to achieve this that would be much appreciated, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is the question about "load image into canvas, edit canvas, save canvas as an image" or something else?

Comment: Please search for existing solutions, if that comes in empty, please edit your question to make it more generic, i.e. not only car renal ;-)

Comment: last part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl

Comment: middle part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899799/whats-the-best-way-to-set-a-single-pixel-in-an-html5-canvas

Comment: first part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas

Comment: thanks All i used fabric.js for implement my solution its work fine for me :)