# Unable to remove outline on HTML5 canvas arc

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, automatic-ref-counting

I am attempting to make a sort of progress bar using HTML5 Canvas Arc's.

The issue I am having is that my arc has a dark outline around it which I cannot change the color of. Below is a picture showing what I mean.

[image]

The code I am using is as follows.

```
function drawArmor( percent ) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('ArmorCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius = 36;
    var startAngle = (3 * Math.PI) / 2;
    var percentLeft = 1;
    var endAngle = -(Math.PI/2) + (Math.PI * 2 ) * ( 1 - percent );

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.lineCap = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = '#FFF';
    context.arc(100, 100, radius, startAngle, endAngle, true);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawHealth( percent ) {
    var HealthText = document.getElementById( "HealthText" );
    HealthText.innerHTML = ( percent * 100 ) + "%";

    var canvas = document.getElementById('HealthCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius = 26;
    var startAngle = (3 * Math.PI) / 2;
    var endAngle = -(Math.PI/2) + (Math.PI * 2 ) * ( 1 - percent );

    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.lineCap = 1;
    context.strokeStyle = '#00FE67';
    context.arc(100, 100, radius, startAngle - 0.00001, endAngle + 0.00001, true);
    context.stroke();
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Creating a jsFiddle would be beneficial.

Comment: Looks like it's caused by anti-aliasing. You'll need to make the line thicker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175042/canvas-arc-clearing

Answer (score 0):

Oops?

The code you present does not draw the image you present so I assume you're using different code that's causing your ring artifacts.

Anyway!

I do see that you're not beginning your path commands with beginPath (your context.arc is a path command).

The lack of beginPath causes the path to be redrawn with each new context.stroke command.

The accumulation of over-draws will cause the kind of artifacts that you describe.

The artifacting is likely caused by repeated overdrawing of the anti-aliasing on your stroke.

So...

Put `context.beginPath` before your context.arc commands and the artifacts might disappear.

If the artifacts don't disappear, we'll need to see your actual code.