# Rotated DIV edges blurry in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alias

I have an audio post where the information is in rotated DIVs that are displayed on top of the album art. To see what I mean go [here (the page).](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com/) The area on the bottom left corner is the information. When viewed in Chrome you will see that the edges of the DIVs are blurred. Is there a way to "alias" the DIVs so they appear sharp? I know it's not a resolution thing because Firefox displays them perfectly.

```
.audioBox {
position:absolute;
bottom:160px;
margin-left:-11px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
z-index:3;
width:343px;
}

.boxify {
margin:1px;
padding:5px;
float:left;
bottom:0;
width:329px;
}

.box {
background:#000; 
padding:5px;
padding-left:10px;
padding-right:10px;
margin-left:-5px;
}

<div class="audioHolder">
<div class="audioBox">

<div class="boxify" id="song">

                    <img id="audioBubble"    
src="http://static.tumblr.com/ux4v5bf/JC6lpv4v1/audio.png">

{block:TrackName}
<span class="box">{TrackName}</span>
{/block:TrackName}
</div>

<div class="boxify" id="artist">
{block:Artist}
<span class="box">{Artist}</span>
{/block:Artist}
</div>

<div class="boxify" id="label">
<span class="box">{PlayCountWithLabel}</span>
</div>

<div class="boxify" id="download">
<span class="box">Download
{block:ExternalAudio}
<a href="{ExternalAudioURL}">Download</a>
{/block:ExternalAudio}</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Solution: I replaced the background color with a background image of the same color instead. :-) Hope it helps somebody else with a similar problem.

Comment: Aliasing is not possible in CSS . Anti Aliasing is controlled by browser .

Comment: So there is no real solution to this?

Comment: You can browse through other thread about control anti aliasing but this was for canvas http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element

Comment: Would replacing it with a background image sharpen it? Because there is actually a black square thats covering up the song title at the bottom and it seems to be sharp even though it's rotated as well.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm little late but...

I have similar problem now and in my case changing the size helps, just use even numbers

```
.blurry {
    left: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 135px;
}

.sharp { 
    left: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 136px;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/_hags/9e4cS/

Comment: A little late? This post was in 2011!