# How to select HTML5 canvas shapes?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a HTML5 canvas on which I have drawn several shapes.

What I want to happen, is that when the mouse is clicked on any shape the shape should get selected (at least it can tell what kind of shape is selected).

Thank you.

Comment: You can use canvas library like [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com) for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using an existing canvas library (or create your own) that has an event when a shape is being selected.

The example below uses the [Kinetic JS library](http://www.kineticjs.com/), and the example below is from [HTML5 Canvas Region Events Example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/):

```
var triangle = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
    var context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.fillStyle = "#00D2FF";
    context.moveTo(120, 50);
    context.lineTo(250, 80);
    context.lineTo(150, 170);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
});

triangle.on("mouseout", function(){
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "Mouseout triangle");
});

triangle.on("mousemove", function(){
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var x = mousePos.x - 120;
    var y = mousePos.y - 50;
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "x: " + x + ", y: " + y);
});

shapesLayer.add(triangle);

var circle = new Kinetic.Shape(function(){
    var canvas = this.getCanvas();
    var context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(380, canvas.height / 2, 70, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.stroke();
});

circle.on("mouseover", function(){
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "Mouseover circle");
});
circle.on("mouseout", function(){
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "Mouseout circle");
});
circle.on("mousedown", function(){
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "Mousedown circle");
});
circle.on("mouseup", function(){
    writeMessage(messageLayer, "Mouseup circle");
});

shapesLayer.add(circle);

stage.add(shapesLayer);
stage.add(messageLayer);
```

In addition, I have included some mouse-in detection if the cursor is within the shape, without using any javascript libraries.

Rectangular-based mouse-in detection:

```
function isCursorWithinRectangle(x, y, width, height, mouseX, mouseY) {
    if(mouseX > x && mouseX < x + width && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + height) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Circle-based mouse-in detection:

```
function isCursorWithinCircle(x, y, r, mouseX, mouseY) {
    var distSqr = Math.pow(x - mouseX, 2) + Math.pow(y - mouseY, 2);

    if(distSqr < r * r) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a very simple way to select complex shapes with pixel precision that doesn't involve bounding rectangles or math calculations.

The idea is that you duplicate all of your shapes onto a hidden secondary canvas, where you assign each shape a unique color. When you perform a mouseover or click event on the original canvas, you save the mouse's (x, y) coordinates in relation to the visible canvas, and then you look-up the pixel color on your hidden canvas using those same coordinates. Because each shape has a unique color on the hidden canvas, that color corresponds to the exact shape that the user selected.

Note that this only supports up to roughly 16.7 million shapes because RGB only has 24 bits of color, but that should be more than enough.

Here's a simple example using D3 and Canvas: http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/6645345

Comment: also there's alpha channel from which we get ~4b different colors

Comment: Yes and no. You can't use the alpha channel if you draw overlapping objects because the RGBA colors would blend together.

Comment: update: I'm using this method for a while and I noticed that if mouse is over the edge of shape, then it's color will differ than shape's color, and then other objects will be selected.
However, I'm using distance=4, and it seems ok for me. But in the future I think I have to create some distance function to eliminate false selections.

Comment: The problem is due to antialiasing. As far as I can tell, you can't truly disable antialiasing, so there's no easy solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element

Answer (score 3):

Canvas does not have an interface for the *elements* on it like the DOM. It is solely used for drawing.

You need to create your assets as objects and use a drawing loop to paint them. You then forget about the `canvas` element, you work with your objects, with their offsets, etc.