# SVG / Canvas :: shape-rendering="crispEdges" via JavaScript?

Tags: graphics, canvas, svg

I want to turn off anti-aliasing and I believe I need to set **shape-rendering** to *"crispEdges"* for that.

How can I do that with ***JavaScript*** ?

This a a part of my code where I need turn off anti-aliasing:

```
context.strokeStyle = gradient;
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.moveTo(x + size, y + size);
context.lineTo(x + dx, y + dy);
context.stroke();
```

So lines should look like the one on right, and not other one on left.

[image]

Every help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SVG you can set the 'shape-rendering' property e.g like this:

```
someElement.style.shapeRendering = "crispEdges";
```

Or as an attribute:

```
someElement.setAttribute("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
```

HTML5 canvas has no way for toggling anti-aliasing on/off, some reasons why are given by Ian Hickson in [this thread](http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2007-May/011263.html).

Comment: It is possible with SVG elements in Firefox, Chrome has issues with shape-rendering