# Last line drawn in javascript isn't like the others

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an issue drawing on `<canvas>` wherein this segment of my code, which draws musical staves on canvas, always makes the last line drawn lighter and almost fading away, no matter what browser is used.

```
window.onload = draw;

function draw() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('sheetmusic');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var whitespace = 0; // pixel space between staves
    var ycoordinate = 10; // y-plot of beginning of each staff

    //draw the staves 'x' number of times requested
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {

        // draw the staff
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            c.strokeStyle = 'black';
            c.moveTo(0,ycoordinate);
            c.lineTo(canvas.width,ycoordinate);
            c.stroke();
            ycoordinate = ycoordinate + 10;
        }

        //draw white space beneath each staff
        c.fillStyle = 'white';
        c.fillRect(0,whitespace + 52,canvas.width,45);
        whitespace = whitespace + 100;
        ycoordinate = ycoordinate + 50;

    }
}
```

The solution I have, since I used a loop to draw the lines is to redraw each line once, when in fact all I really need is draw the very last line one more time.

```
    window.onload = draw;

    function draw() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('sheetmusic');
        var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var whitespace = 0; // pixel space between staves
        var ycoordinate = 10; // y-plot of beginning of each staff

    //draw the staves 'x' number of times requested
    for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++) {

        // draw the staff
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
            c.strokeStyle = 'black';
            c.moveTo(0,ycoordinate);
            c.lineTo(canvas.width,ycoordinate);
            c.stroke();
            // this code repeats to alleviate bug with last drawn line not being defined enough
            c.moveTo(0,ycoordinate);
            c.lineTo(canvas.width,ycoordinate);
            c.stroke();
            ycoordinate = ycoordinate + 10;
        }

        //draw white space beneath each staff
        c.fillStyle = 'white';
        c.fillRect(0,whitespace + 52,canvas.width,45);
        whitespace = whitespace + 100;
        ycoordinate = ycoordinate + 50;

    }
}
```

**Any ideas on how to redraw the last line once more?**

Keep in mind, when the rest of this web app is implemented my `x` variable will need to be changed via clicked option, therefore letting the amount of staves be as little or much as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Should learn the basics of `lineWidth` property in canvas ..

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/canvas-tutorial/4_5_canvas_linewidth.html)

Solution : For even stroke widths you can use integers for coordinates, for odd stroke widths you want to use .5 to get crisp lines that fill the pixels correctly.

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/KcTfH/) too ...

Unfortunately , no other solution for this ... Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978771/line-width-in-html5-canvas)

Comment: Thanks, Prasath K, your example Fiddle is what I finally understood.  From what I can tell, this is somewhat of a bug in the community?  Had to change my y-coordinate by .5 to finally get crisp lines, and add the lineWidth property with a value of 1.