# Unexpected canvas behavior when using stroke style

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to clear one line by drawing another one on top of it on HTML canvas. But the second line becomes semi transparent for some unknown to me reason.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<html>

    <body onload = "onload()">
        <canvas id = "canvas" style="border: solid 1px; width: 200px; height: 200px;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

scripts.js

```
var canvas,ctx;
const onload = () =>{
    canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    drawLine("#ff0000")
    drawLine("#ffffff")
}

const drawLine = (color) =>{
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = color
    ctx.moveTo(0,0)
    ctx.lineTo(200,200)
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()
}
```

```js
var canvas,ctx;
const onload = () =>{
    canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    drawLine("#ff0000")
    drawLine("#ffffff")
}

const drawLine = (color) =>{
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = color
    ctx.moveTo(0,0)
    ctx.lineTo(200,200)
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<html>

    <body onload = "onload()">
        <canvas id = "canvas" style="border: solid 1px; width: 200px; height: 200px;"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, `width` and `height` of a `<canvas>` should be set as attributes, not as CSS properties. See [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](/q/2588181/4642212). Please see [How to create Stack Snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/4642212). I don’t see a second line. Also, the `ctx.closePath()` at the end does nothing. Remove it.

Comment: Converted your code into a snippet. I do not see a problem with it. Maybe something inside your project is problematic that you did not share here.

Comment: If you set `ctx.lineWidth = 10` you will see that the problem is not the opacity of the new line but the old line leaking from the edges.

Comment: This question might be of interest:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element