# Drawing image to canvas changes the color

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I tried to draw this image to canvas.
https://res.cloudinary.com/casestry-com/image/upload/casestry-studio/render/14PMT/p1/black/2500x3000/gloss_mask.png
In my local I checked that the rgb color at (551, 1439) is (18, 255, 255)
But when I get the color after drawing the image to canvas the color is changed to (9, 255, 255)
Is there any way to get the same color after drawing to canvas?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/badu3ze6/5/

```
async function getImage(url) {
  const imageLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = () => {
      resolve(image);
    };
  });
  return imageLoadPromise;
}
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
async function loadImage() {
    const img = await getImage("https://res.cloudinary.com/casestry-com/image/upload/casestry-studio/render/14PMT/p1/black/2500x3000/gloss_mask.png");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const data = ctx.getImageData(551, 1439, 1, 1).data;
  try{
    console.log('read by canvas:', [data[0], data[1], data[2]])
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function readByImageJs() {
    let image = await IJS.Image.load("https://res.cloudinary.com/casestry-com/image/upload/casestry-studio/render/14PMT/p1/black/2500x3000/gloss_mask.png");
  console.log('read by imagejs:', image.getPixelXY(551, 1439));
}

loadImage()
readByImageJs();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element). Look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67800821/5089567

Comment: No it didn't worked.

Comment: `image.getPixelXY(` is part of a 3rd party image loader. The problem must be in its code. Check their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your image does declare an ICC color profile, but doesn't embed it.
Both Chrome and Firefox will choke on it, apparently trying to convert from *something* to *sRGB* while the color profile is actually set to sRGB (IEC61966-2.1). (Note that Safari does return the same values as *image-js*).

If your image had its color profile embedded, both Firefox and Chrome would have been able to decode it too. If your image was declared as RGB without a color profile, they'd also have been able to handle it correctly.

If you can't modify your image, you can also force the browser to not try to manage the color of the image, through the [`createImageBitmap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) method and its `colorSpaceConversion` option:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
async function loadImage() {
  const resp = await fetch("https://res.cloudinary.com/casestry-com/image/upload/casestry-studio/render/14PMT/p1/black/2500x3000/gloss_mask.png")
  const blob = await resp.blob();
  const img = await createImageBitmap(blob, {
    colorSpaceConversion: "none"
  });
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const data = ctx.getImageData(551, 1439, 1, 1).data;
  try {
    console.log('read by canvas:', [data[0], data[1], data[2]])
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

async function readByImageJs() {
  let image = await IJS.Image.load("https://res.cloudinary.com/casestry-com/image/upload/casestry-studio/render/14PMT/p1/black/2500x3000/gloss_mask.png");
  console.log('read by imagejs:', image.getPixelXY(551, 1439));
}

loadImage()
readByImageJs();
```

```html
<span id="pixel"></span>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
<script src="https://www.lactame.com/lib/image-js/0.21.2/image.min.js"></script>
```