# How do I completely remove font smoothing from bitmap fonts? Is the solution possible with Javascript?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, texture-atlas

On my current website, I am trying to render everything pixelated with sprite graphics and pixel fonts to make it look as close to a game as possible. The problem is that Chrome and Firefox like to render pixel fonts differently and there isn't a way to make them look consistent. This especially happens when trying to center the font or use css transform. It always defaults to anti-aliasing it.

Just for reference, [here is the font](https://www.dafont.com/pixeltiny.font) I am trying to render dynamically:

Firefox: [image: Firefox Render Example]

Chrome: [image]

Notice how it looks crystal clear on Firefox while blurry in Chrome.

I have attempted to try all sorts of css tricks to fix this with no luck, including some methods listed in [this](https://github.com/DavidBuchanan314/bitmap-font-css) interesting Github repo. Then I came across some game development forums where they were discussing using a texture atlas to import their fonts in their games.

[Here is an example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-text-glyphs.html). In the second half of the page, you can see they are using a sprite sheet with all the font letters laid out, then using code to assign each part to a letter and insert it into their WebGL example. I would like to do the same thing, except in my case have it dynamically reference what I typed and insert it where my example text is.

I'm sure there is a way this could be done in Javascript, or maybe there is another solution somebody else has already come up with that I just haven't thought of yet. Any ideas?

Here is an example of what the code looks like:

```css
:root {
  --multiplication-factor: 1;
  --number-shadow: #002806;
  --text-shadow: #4b4b54;
  --font-size: 16px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: pixeltiny;
  src: url(https://old.sgxp.me/example/PixelTiny.ttf);
}

body {
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.sprite-page-container {
  margin: 20px 105px;
}

.sprite-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.sprite-box {  
  width: calc(117px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  height: calc(188px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  background-image: url('https://old.sgxp.me/example/icon_image.svg');
  margin: 10px;
  user-select: none;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .2s;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  animation: fadein-top .7s;
}

.sprite-box:hover {
  transform: translateY(calc(-5px * var(--multiplication-factor)));
  animation: fadein-top .7s;
}

.sprite-page-container a {
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}

.sprite-page-container a:hover {
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url("https://old.sgxp.me/example/icon_image.svg");
}

.sprite-page-container a:visited {
  color: white;
}

.sprite-star-container {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: calc(6px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-top: calc(3px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-bottom: calc(-9px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  width: calc(70px * var(--multiplication-factor));
}

.sprite-star {
  height: calc(6px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  width: calc(7px * var(--multiplication-factor));
}

.sprite-star:nth-child(n + 2) {
  margin-left: calc(-1px * var(--multiplication-factor));
}

.sprite-number {
  font-family: 'pixeltiny', monospace;
  font-size: calc(var(--font-size) * var(--multiplication-factor));
  color: white;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: calc(6px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-top: calc(3px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  text-shadow: calc(1px * var(--multiplication-factor)) 0px var(--number-shadow), 0px calc(1px * var(--multiplication-factor)) var(--number-shadow), calc(1px * var(--multiplication-factor)) calc(1px * var(--multiplication-factor)) var(--number-shadow);
}

.sprite-text {
  font-family: 'pixeltiny', monospace;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: calc(var(--font-size) * var(--multiplication-factor));
  line-height: calc(7px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  text-align: center;
  color:white;
}

.sprite-title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: calc(4px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-left: calc(5px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-right: calc(10px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  height: calc(15px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  width: calc(109px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.sprite-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  pointer-events: none;
  height: calc(71px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  width: calc(103px * var(--multiplication-factor));  
  margin-top: calc(5px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-left: calc(7px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-right: calc(6px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sprite-image > img {
  filter: drop-shadow(calc(10px * var(--multiplication-factor)) calc(10px * var(--multiplication-factor)) 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.7));
  transform: scale(calc(1 * var(--multiplication-factor)));
}

.sprite-author {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: calc(-2px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-left: calc(13px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-right: calc(12px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-bottom: calc(0spx * var(--multiplication-factor));
  height: calc(26px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  width: calc(93px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  overflow-wrap: anywhere;
}

.sprite-stats {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: calc(4px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-left: calc(24px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  margin-right: calc(3px * var(--multiplication-factor));
  width: calc(110px * var(--multiplication-factor));
}

.sprite-stats:nth-child(n+2) {
  height: calc(5px * var(--multiplication-factor));
}

@keyframes fadein-top {
  0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-50px);}
  50% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-50px);}
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
}
```

```html
<div class="sprite-container">
  <a href="" class="sprite-box">
    <div class="sprite-star-container">
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
      <div class="sprite-star"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-number">001</div>
    <div class="sprite-title">
      <div id="author" class="sprite-text">Example</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-image">
      <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-author">
      <div class="sprite-text">Example</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-stats">
      <div class="sprite-text">Example</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-stats">
      <div class="sprite-text">Example</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-stats">
      <div class="sprite-text">Exmaple</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sprite-stats">
      <div class="sprite-text">Exmaple</div>
    </div>
  </a>
 </div>
```

As you can see, I am dynamically putting the example text over my svg image. Everything in the svg looks fine, but when I insert my text Chrome renders it with this weird font smoothing.

Comment: To some extent you can mitigate this undesired anti-aliasing effect by applying a svg 
 `feComponentTransfer` filter See this answer by Kaiido["Can I turn off antialiasing on an HTML <canvas> element?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195262/can-i-turn-off-antialiasing-on-an-html-canvas-element#69718616)

Comment: @herrstrietzel Would you be able to provide a practical example of this based on my code snippet?

Comment: Its just mitigates this effect. but you might tweak the setting. You will also have to avoid any centering causing floating point pixel values. Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/poYEyWQ)

Comment: @herrstrietzel this is an interesting solution and I toyed around with it on your codepen for a fair bit of time. It could possibly fit my usecase if we could 1. Somehow get the black box around the letters to be transparent or at the very least have the box  be the height of the letters and 2. Find some way to make it dynamic to whatever I type, as it seems that after trying to modify the text to different words we are left with a bunch of junk font at the end.